# Mouseover to get div to appear within the border of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I hover over an `img` within `div.hover-group`, the div `div.hover-toggle` becomes visible, and becomes invisible when the mouse leaves the image.
The `div.hover-toggle` should appear within the area of the `img` it belongs to, **aligned with its bottom border** and each of the `button.btn`s **of equal width**.

To illustrate:

no mouseover:

```
|-----------|
|           |
|    img    |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|-----------|
```

is mouseover:

```
|-----------|
|           |
|    img    |
|           |
|-----------|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-----------|
```

I have already accomplished the hover toggling using jQuery:

```
$(selector1).mouseover(function(){$(selector2).hide();});
$(selector1).mouseout(function(){$(selector2).show();});
```

However, have been unable to align `div.hover-toggle` with the bottom of the image, as illustrated, it appears below the image instead.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

---

The DOM I am manipulating above appears below. It uses twitter bootstrap.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="hover-group thumbnail">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
            <div class="hover-toggle btn-group">
                <button class="btn">1</button>
                <button class="btn">2</button>
                <button class="btn">3</button>
            </div>
            <h5>Thumbnail label</h5>
            <p>Thumbnail caption right here...</p>
        </div>
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for JS here, you can accomplish everything with simple CSS and a little markup change (I wrapped the image and the .hover-toggle div in a .image-wrapper div):

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="hover-group thumbnail">
            <div class="image-wrapper">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
              <div class="hover-toggle btn-group">
                  <button class="btn">1</button>
                  <button class="btn">2</button>
                  <button class="btn">3</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h5>Thumbnail label</h5>
            <p>Thumbnail caption right here...</p>
        </div>
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

Now the styling it needs is simple:

```
.hover-group .image-wrapper {
  /* We need this to make the .hover-toggle div relative to .image-wrapper */
  position: relative;
}

.hover-group .image-wrapper .hover-toggle {
  /* set it at the bottom of .image-wrapper */
  position: absolute;      
  bottom: 0;
  /* and don't display it */
  display: none;
}

.hover-group .image-wrapper:hover .hover-toggle {
  /* only display it when .image-wrapper is being hovered on */
  display: block;
}
```

If you want it to show when you hover over the whole .hover-group, use this CSS instead of the last line:

```
.hover-group:hover .image-wrapper .hover-toggle {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, here is a demo i created with the answer i was writing (which is almost the same): http://jsfiddle.net/W2uNA/

Comment: @AndresIlich , @ yoavmatchulsky : A couple of things:

1) I would like to have these buttons of equal width, and their total width equal to that of the image

2) Could you verify that this technique plays well with Twitter Bootstrap? (jsfiddle says js only, I assume this leaves out TB's css)
I did try creating a `div.image-wrapper` like yourself, but this caused either `ul.thumbnails` or `div.thumbnail` to appear weird. I assume because its CSS selector looks for a `div` that is a direct descendant of `.thumbnail`, or similar.

Comment: @bguiz just divide 100 into three and use the results asa width for each button.

Comment: @ Andres : Set `.hover-toggle .btn` to have `width:33.2%;`, and it worked with minor tweaks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your structure unchanged, you could set height of div.hover-toggle then set margin of the image as below:

```
margin:0 0 -30px 0;
```

which 30 is an appropriate number depends on the height of div.hover-toggle.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4geFu/

Comment: @ Kasra : Thank you for your answer, I like it, but I felt that the other solution was more elegant because it avoid specifying an absolute pixel size of the `div`